# Are there memory restrictions on iOS that cause an app to crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app crashes right after it starts. I think it has something to do with me defining two large arrays in this init function:

```
- (AppIndex*)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        float rgba[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        range = [Text make:@"50 mi" font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:30] color:rgba width:1000];
        [range centerOnX:420 Y:10 width:121 height:40];
        mode = [Text make:@"Relevant" font:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:30] color:rgba width:1000];
        [mode centerOnX:100 Y:10 width:121 height:40];
        NSString* wow = @"WOW";
        Vertex vertices[] = {
            // Bottom bar
            {{640, 0}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},
            {{640, 60}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},
            {{0, 60}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},
            {{0, 0}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},

            // Top bar
            {{640, [OpenGLView screenHeight] - 60}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},
            {{640, [OpenGLView screenHeight]}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},
            {{0, [OpenGLView screenHeight]}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},
            {{0, [OpenGLView screenHeight] - 60}, {250, 166, 104, 127}},

            // Background
            {{640, 0}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, 0}},
            {{640, [OpenGLView screenHeight]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, [OpenGLView screenHeight] / 16.0f}},
            {{0, [OpenGLView screenHeight]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {[OpenGLView screenWidth] / 16.0f, [OpenGLView screenHeight] / 16.0f}},
            {{0, 0}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {[OpenGLView screenWidth] / 16.0f, 0}},

            // Icons
            {{50, 7}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(294), C(45)}},
            {{50, 52}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(294), 0}},
            {{7, 52}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(337), 0}},
            {{7, 7}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(337), C(45)}},

            {{259, 8}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(121), C(40)}},
            {{380, 8}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(242), C(40)}},
            {{259, 48}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(121), 0}},
            {{380, 48}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(242), 0}},

            {{585, 11}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(244), C(40)}},
            {{633, 11}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(292), C(40)}},
            {{585, 51}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(244), 0}},
            {{633, 51}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(292), 0}},

            {{100, 10}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, C(40)}},
            {{221, 10}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(121), C(40)}},
            {{100, 50}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, 0}},
            {{221, 50}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(121), 0}},

            {{420, 10}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, C(40)}},
            {{541, 10}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(121), C(40)}},
            {{420, 50}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, 0}},
            {{541, 50}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {C(121), 0}},

            {{[range X], [range Y]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, [range TY]}},
            {{[range X2], [range Y]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {[range TX], [range TY]}},
            {{[range X], [range Y2]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, 0}},
            {{[range X2], [range Y2]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {[range TX], 0}},

            {{[mode X], [mode Y]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, [mode TY]}},
            {{[mode X2], [mode Y]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {[mode TX], [mode TY]}},
            {{[mode X], [mode Y2]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {0, 0}},
            {{[mode X2], [mode Y2]}, {255, 255, 255, 0}, {[mode TX], 0}}
        };
        GLuint vertexSize = 40;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vertexSize; i++) {
            vertices[i].position[0] = X(vertices[i].position[0]);
            vertices[i].position[1] = Y(vertices[i].position[1], [OpenGLView screenHeight]);
        }
        GLushort indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0,

            4, 5, 6,
            6, 7, 4,

            8, 9, 10,
            10, 11, 8,

            12, 13, 14,
            14, 15, 12,

            16, 17, 19,
            16, 19, 18,

            20, 21, 23,
            20, 23, 22,

            24, 25, 27,
            24, 27, 26,

            28, 29, 31,
            28, 31, 30,

            32, 33, 35,
            32, 35, 34,

            36, 37, 39,
            36, 39, 38
        };
        GLuint indexSize = 60;
        icons = [OpenGLView setupTexture:@"icons.png"];
        background = [OpenGLView setupTexture:@"tile.png"];
        [self vboWithVertices:vertices count:vertexSize indices:indices count:indexSize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)vboWithVertices:(Vertex[])vertices count:(GLuint)countV indices:(GLushort[])indices count:(GLuint)countI {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    NSLog(@"%u", sizeof(Vertex));
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, countV * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, countI * sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

This does a couple of things. `range` and `mode` are two textures being loaded. So are `icons` and `background`. Those huge arrays are also copied to a VBO at the end.

This worked up to a certain point where I could add things to my app. Now if I add one line to the same function, it will crash. Like even this:

```
NSString* wow = @"Wow";
```

It won't crash if I add lines outside the function with the arrays (presumably because some memory has been freed).

My app will crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. If I comment out the two large arrays, my app works so I think it is a memory issue. But not that much memory is even used. When the app crashes Xcode says that it ran for < 1ms and the memory has a high of 6.4MB and a low of 6.4MB.

Anyways, these arrays are just placeholders, I will get more organized. Is there a remedy for this? And can someone explain why it is crashing?

Comment: Can you post your entire `init` method? You can also try profiling using the "Zombies" profiler in Instruments, to see if that will help show you exactly what the root problem is.

Comment: iOS has limit on amount of memory that can be allocated but arrays you have are quite small. EXC_BAD_ACCESS does not mean you allocated too much memory. It means you tried to access invalid memory region.

Comment: All right, well I posted the full function. If I add, in the bounds of the if-statement- an `NSString` or allocate any other objects it crashes. If I allocate an object in an `autoreleasepool` in the if-statement it doesn't crash. That's why I thought it was a memory issue.

Comment: It probably *is* a memory issue, just not the kind you think it is. :) My money would be on corruption of some sort.

Comment: What are some causes of corruption? I don't really malloc/free stuff, and I'm using ARC so I don't release things.

Comment: You are writing past the vertices array end. It does not have 42 entries

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that you're creating sizable arrays on the stack. I'm not sure what the stack size is on iOS devices, but if you were to write past the end of the stack, weird stuff could happen.

Comment: Those arrays are trivial, size-wise.  Daij-Djan appears to have the answer -- you're allocating the arrays on the stack, sticking them into an object, and then returning.  When you return the stack-allocated arrays go "poof".

Comment: @yurish oops! That doesn't solve the problem though :(

Comment: Please update the code. And what do you have in vboWithVertices? Also try to execute code step-by-step in debugger and see where it crashes. In the updated code you made vertexSize even larger

Comment: I added the function at the bottom, I'll try to run the code line by line now.

Comment: The program gets `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the line with the closing brace, right before `return self`.

Comment: I suspect you're passing the address of a temporary to a function (`glBufferData()`) that holds onto the pointer and expects it to be there after `init` has completed.

Comment: You have only 40 entries in vertices array why did you set vertexSize to 50? I would recommend use macros for determining size of stack allocated arrays. Something like `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. Have you tried to step into vboWithVertices?

Comment: Oops that was a typo editing it here... I should go to sleep. No, that wasn't the problem. @marko I think you are right... If I make `vertices` and `indices` instance variables everything works... Why? I thought `glBufferData` copied the data??

Comment: Actually, now I can't even reproduce the problem.. I am confused. Oh well

Comment: @user3100783 That's a surefire sign of object lifetime issue.  All depends what happens with the memory in the time between it going out of scope and later crashing.

Answer (score 1):

the array data is all on the stack AFAICS... dont put it on the stack